# Multivalidator form_field_validator List<> FormValidator

Tags: flutter

I need to create a Required Validator and a date validator with form_field_validator in flutter , inside the attibute validator requires me a list of validators, and i use only the required validator, and i want to use another custom.

```
textForm() async {
  TextEditingController nameVisitorController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController fechaDiagnosticoController = TextEditingController();
  controllers.add(nameVisitorController);
  controllers2.add(fechaDiagnosticoController);
  final FocusNode _nodeText1 = FocusNode();
  _children = List.from(_children)
    ..add(Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Color(0XFFDBDBDB),
              width: 1, //                   <--- border width here
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'Fecha del diagnóstico ' +
                        (_children.length + 1).toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Color(0XFF3D3C3C)),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  ))
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
                  child: GenericDateTimePickerBanorteWidget(
                    controller: fechaDiagnosticoController,
                    validator: [
                      RequiredValidator(errorText: "Campo obligatorio"),
                    ],
                  )),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'Diagnóstico ' +
                        (_children.length + 1).toString() +
                        ' (Obligatorio)',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Color(0XFF3D3C3C)),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  ))
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              GenericTextInputBanorteWidget(
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                controller: nameVisitorController,
                obscureText: false,
                enabled: true,
                hintText: 'Escribe el diagnóstico de tu informe médico.',
                length: 70,
                maxLines: 3,
                inputFormatter: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(""),
                  //FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[A-Z a-z 0-9]')),
                ],
                validator: [
                  RequiredValidator(errorText: "Campo obligatorio"),

                ],
                onChanged: (e) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
}
```

This is my Required Validator

```
class RequiredValidator extends TextFieldValidator {
  RequiredValidator({required String errorText}) : super(errorText);

  @override
  bool get ignoreEmptyValues => false;

  @override
  bool isValid(String? value) {
    return value!.isNotEmpty;
  }

  @override
  String? call(String? value) {
    return isValid(value) ? null : errorText;
  }
}
```

Example of the validator that i need

```
validator: [
                        RequiredValidator(errorText: "Campo obligatorio"),
                        DateValidator(errorText: "required", date: date)
                      ],
```

validator: [
RequiredValidator(errorText: "Campo obligatorio"),
DateValidator(errorText: "Campo obligatorio"),
],

```
Thanks you a lot

  

I tried creating a custom form_field_validador, but i dont know how to call it back
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input being validated is based on text input consider extend the `TextFieldValidator`.

```
class DateValidator extends TextFieldValidator {
  // pass the error text to the super constructor
  DateValidator({String errorText = 'Please enter a valid date'})
      : super(errorText);

  // return false if you want the validator to return error
  // message when the value is empty.
  @override
  bool get ignoreEmptyValues => true;

  @override
  bool isValid(String? value) {
    if (value == null) return true;
    final result = DateTime.tryParse(value);
    return result != null;
  }
}
```

Another way of doing the same is by extending `FieldValidator`

```
class CustomDateValidator<T> extends FieldValidator<T> {
  CustomDateValidator(super.errorText);

  @override
  bool isValid(T value) {
    if (value is! String) return false;
    final result = DateTime.tryParse(value);
    return result != null;
  }
}
```

The code samples are taken from the [official documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/form_field_validator)

Now instead of

```
validator: [
  RequiredValidator(errorText: "Campo obligatorio"),
  DateValidator(errorText: "required", date: date),
]
```

use

```
MultiValidator([
    RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Campo obligatorio'),
    CustomDateValidator('required'),
    // DateValidator(),
 ]
```